# GitPython Issue when pushing a new local tag

Tags: git, tags, push, gitpython

I created a tag using

`git tag -a test -m test`

Now, I would like to push just this tag, but GitPython is reporting that I am not in the repository.  Even though I can push the change commit just fine.

So this works:

```
repo = git.Repo('some_repo')
repo.git.push('origin', 'some_branch')
```

However, pushing the tag like this, it does not work.

`repo.git.push('origin', 'refs/tags/test:refs/tags/test')`

Here is the error message:

**
  cmdline: git push origin refs/tags/test:refs/tags/test
  stderr: '10:40:49.939695 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git push origin refs/tags/test:refs/tags/test
error: src refspec refs/tags/test does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.mot-solutions.com:7999/astro_sub/scm_tools.git''
**

I basically just want to run this command using GitPython:

`git push origin refs/tags/test:refs/tags/test`

How do I do this?

Keep in mind that I did not use the repo.create_tag function to create the tag.

Comment: Can you push by just the tag name? `repo.git.push('origin', 'test')`

Comment: It gives an error that I am not in a repo or something like that:  ````cmdline: git push origin test
  stderr: '12:04:57.601700 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git push origin test
error: src refspec test does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to '<URL>'' ```

Answer (score 1):

have used gitpython recently.

Try:

```
repo.remotes.origin.push(tag)
```

Comment: unfortunately, that would only work for the "origin" remote.

Comment: Have you tried with other remotes? Why only work for the "origin" remote? As my repo has only "origin" remote.